# "run-multiple" command seem that it ignores "emulate" and all other options

Tags: codeceptjs, playwright, e2e

I'm using "codeceptjs (3.0.2)" with the playwright helpers (1.4.2; if I run the command:
`codeceptjs run-multiple basic`

with this configuration:

```
 multiple: {
    basic: {
      chunks: process.env.THREADS || 30,
      browsers: [
        {
          browser: 'webkit',
          windowSize: '100x100',
        },
        {
          browser: 'firefox',
          windowSize: '1920x1080',
        },
      ],
    },
  },
```

It completely ignore windowSize and all other param (e.g emulation):

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the `setWindowSize` from the [@codeceptjs/configure](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@codeceptjs/configure) library.

For instance:

```
// import the setWindowSize function   
const { setWindowSize } = require('@codeceptjs/configure');

// Set window size
setWindowSize(600, 600);
```